# How to save/load trained model in Shogun?

Tags: c++, shogun

How to save/load trained model in Shogun? Didn't find in docs.

https://www.shogun-toolbox.org/examples/latest/quickstart/interfaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on what version you are using. in case release here's an example: https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/blob/master/examples/undocumented/libshogun/library_serialization.cpp

if you are using develop then simply use

```
...
auto jsonSerilizer = std::make_shared<io::JsonSerializer>();
obj.serialize(jsonSerilizer);
...
```